# Encrypt chat messages stored in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, encryption, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an application in which chatting is also a feature for which I am using firebase realtime database. Though all the data stored in firebase is via SSL but I want that even the administration is not able to see that messages.
I thought of implementing the end-to-end encryption by using the public and private key architecture, but storing the private key on device won't be good as a new private key will be created when the phone is uninstalled or even when the app is used in another device and also previous messages won't be decrypted.

I also thought of, if the new messages could be encrypted with the new private key, when generated, and storing the previous chat history in google drive or iCloud as backup, but since this not entirely a chat application I think this won't be feasible.

http://www.geero.net/2017/05/how-to-encrypt-a-google-firebase-realtime-database/

I also went through this article but again the keys will be with the administration.

How should I proceed ?

Comment: encrpt  and descrypt message with AES on device .

Comment: Thanks. But that won't be in sync with other devices. And also the key would have to be sent to the other user and if I am using firebase I will have to store it in database again.

Comment: i dont understand `But that won't be in sync with other devices` and you can use any specific key for encryption and decryption . so no need to store on firebase

Comment: Okeh, so in that case where am I going to store that specific key? In the device? So won't that be more vulnerable as anyone can do reverse engineering and get the key. But again this can be an option though as they can have the key but not access to the database if I configure the security rules correctly. Isn't it ?

Comment: you can use [Android keystore](https://medium.com/@josiassena/using-the-android-keystore-system-to-store-sensitive-information-3a56175a454b) to save your key and wont be vulnerable in case of reverse engineering

Comment: Okeh, but I have one more doubt. I cannot use one specific key for encryption and decryption, no one else but I or the administrator will still be knowing the key.

Comment: i dont understand . what's the prob using one secure key ? and if you want to use multiple keys you're gonna have  to store which key you used for which user_id on server

Comment: The problem using one secure key is only that I as a developer and also the administration will be knowing that key, so maybe in future someone may become a bad guy. And also if I make user specific key then ultimately I'll have to send it over to the user I am chatting with to decrypt it. Now if I have to send it I'll have to write it to the database. Now also suppose I delete the key after decrypting that message then how am I going to decrypt the whole chat history when the user again installs the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recomend you to encrypt your messages with AES. And you should not store the secret key on devices. Otherwise, users can make key agreement to generate shared secret key, using Diffie-Hellman key exchange algorithm:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange

Comment: So where should I store the key? I cannot store it on the server.

Comment: You dont need to store key. Alice and Bob generates their shared secret key. Alice encrypt message via secret key and send it to Bob. Bob decrypt message using shared secret key and can read decrypted message. If you want, you can save decrypted message on Bob's device. 

For next message Bob and Alice generate next shared secret key

Comment: Okeh I understood, I'll have to send the key to Bob supposing I am Alice. Sending the key using the firebase database means writing the key somewhere on that message node so that Bob can get that key to decrypt the msg. So isn't that key there in the db. And also supposing I delete the key after decrypting the recent message and storing the message in the local db. Then what about the case when the user installs the app again after uninstalling it. The old chat history won't get decrypted as the key is not present.

Comment: Yes. After install app on other device, you won't get history from encrypted chat. But as i know thats is how secrets chat works. For example Signal App or Telegram doesnt syncing messages from "secret chats". This apps store history only for default chats without encryption.

Comment: Thanks brother I understood, you are right. My approach was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> Though all the data stored in firebase is via SSL but I want that even the administration is not able to see that messages.

There are already some end-to-end secured messaging protocols (e.g. [Signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_%28software%29)), you may have a look how they work.

> when the app is used in another device and also previous messages won't be decrypted

That's the price for the end-to-end encryption.

You could still somehow distribute the private key between multiple devices e.g. encrypt the private key with user's password and decrypt the key when user authenticates only on the user's device (I am just shooting ideas, you may think it through if it is secure enough)

> storing the previous chat history in google drive or iCloud as backup

Viber and WhatsUp are doing it, the question is if users will trust you enough to give you permissions to access their cloud storage