# AES Decrypted text shows different result everytime the same activity opened

Tags: java, firebase, encryption

The story is I am building a Chatapp application that encrypts messages using AES, the problem is when I try to display the decrypted message, the message is still readable

[image: (figure 1)]

but when I exit the conversation and enter the same conversation again, the text that has been described is decrypted again so it's become gibberish

[image: (picture 2)]

I found out the problem is in the key generation, so when I open the same chat again, it automatically decrypt the message with a different key ...

The question is, how can I display the message so anytime I opened it, it will not show gibberish things again?

Here's the script of the sending and displaying message

```java
final byte[] generatedkey = aesContoh.KeyGen(); //Key generation
 
//When send button pressed
 send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
 
                //Encryption process
                String messageContent = typemessage.getText().toString();
                byte[]  message = messageContent.getBytes();
                byte[] encrypt = Base64.getEncoder().encode(aesContoh.Encrypt(message, generatedkey));
                String encryption = new String(encrypt);
 
                //Add encrypted message to database
                if((!messageContent.equals(""))){
                    Map<String,String> messageTextBody = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    messageTextBody.put("Message",encryption);
                    messageTextBody.put("User", Message.Name);
                    reference1.push().setValue(messageTextBody);
                    reference2.push().setValue(messageTextBody);
                    typemessage.setText("");
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You are not the sender",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
 
        //See the database reference
        reference1.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Map<String,String> map = (Map<String,String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                String message = map.get("Message").toString();
                byte[] pesan = Base64.getDecoder().decode(message); //Get encrypted message from database
                String pengguna = map.get("User").toString(); //Get user data from database
 
                //Decrypt AES
                byte[] decrypt = aesContoh.Decrypt(message, generatedKey);
                Log.d("generated key", Arrays.toString(generatedKey));
                String decryption = new String(decrypt);
 
                if(user.equals(Message.Name)){ //Display message sent
                    addMessageBox(decryption,1);
                }else{ //Display message received
                    addMessageBox(decryption,2);
                }
 
            }
 
        });
 
 
    }
```

**Update**

As suggested in the comment, what I need to do is using Key Exchange, so the sender and the receiver will have the same key, and they can transport it securely...

I found about this [github library](https://github.com/testanull/Diffie-Hellman-in-Java) that show the Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange... and I mixed the comment from [here](https://github.com/firatkucuk/diffie-hellman-helloworld) to the code in the
[github library](https://github.com/testanull/Diffie-Hellman-in-Java)... Like this

```java
package diffiehellman;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class DiffieHellman{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
        int bitlength = 128;

    //Random prime
    BigInteger p = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlength,rand);
    BigInteger g = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlength,rand);

    DHUtil Alice  = new DHUtil(p,g,bitlength);
    DHUtil Bob = new DHUtil(p,g,bitlength);

    //    ?                                        ?
        //
        //    O                                        O
        //   /|\                                      /|\
        //   / \                                      / \
        //
        //  ALICE                                     BOB


    
    //Choose number
    Alice.chooseNumber();
    Bob.chooseNumber();

    Alice.valuetosend();
    Bob.valuetosend();


        //
        //    O                                        O
        //   /|\                                      /|\
        //   / \                                      / \
        //
        //  ALICE                                     BOB
        //  _ PUBLIC KEY                              _ PUBLIC KEY
        //  _ PRIVATE KEY                             _ PRIVATE KEY



    //Receive value
    Alice.Sidekey();
    Bob.Sidekey();    

  //
        //    O                                        O
        //   /|\                                      /|\
        //   / \                                      / \
        //
        //  ALICE                                     BOB
        //  + public key                              + public key
        //  + private key                             + private key
        //  _ PUBLIC KEY <------------------------->  _ PUBLIC KEY




    //Calc final key
    Alice.finalKey();
    Bob.finalKey();  
    
 
        //
        //    O                                        O
        //   /|\ []-------------------------------->  /|\
        //   / \                                      / \
        //
        //  ALICE                                     BOB
        //  + public key                              + public key
        //  + private key                             + private key
        //  + public key                              + public key
        //  + secret key                              + secret key
        //  + message                                 _ MESSAGE

        // 6. ------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Bob receives the important message and decrypts with secret key.   


    }
    
}
```

Unluckily, I still don't understand how do I implement it since I'm using Firebase as the server a.k.a place to store the data of the app...

**Update**
So I'm researching the Firebase thing with Diffie-Hellman, and I stumbled across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54705518/encrypt-chat-messages-stored-in-firebase-database)

The answers explained that you don't have to use Firebase for the process, but there are no explanation how to sending the keys...

I'll researching a bit more on it, if anyone know how the process done, you can answer or explain it in the comment with reference

Comment: Thats Part of your key management.  If it should be possible to read the chat after it was closed you can store the key but that is unsecure. Another way is to generate the key with a function like PBKDF2 but that causes an user input. How is the key exchanged between sender and receipient?

Comment: Yes, I understand that my problem is in my key management...  that's why I'm asking this question...

The process to the key exchange is just like in the code, the encrypted message, sent to database.. listen to the database reference, get the encrypted message, decrypt the message using the key that being generated by 
`final byte[] genkunci = aesContoh.KeyGen()`

Comment: So your code above is working correctly. You need a key exchange like Diffie-Hellmann to FIRST exchange keys and then use the exchanged key for encryption and decryption like WhatsApp.

Comment: In which part do you think best to implement it?

Comment: The key exchange has to be done when two chatpartners meet first time. They exchange the keys, generate a "sharedsecret" and encrypt  (and decrypt) all chats with this new key.

Comment: "The key exchange has to be done when two chatpartners meet first time."

How can I implement it? if i'm using my code above, the key will be generated everytime the chat activity opened... how can I make it "one conversation, one key"?

Comment: A good example is available here: https://github.com/firatkucuk/diffie-hellman-helloworld.

Comment: If there's something wrong on how I interpret it, plz correct me...

Comment: The "security management" is unclear in your business case. Who should be able to read chat content? Of course the sender and the recipient, but should the server been able to have access to the plaintext? Usually the answer is "no" means that there is a "End to End" encryption. If this is the case then the server (the firebase database) only stores the encrypted chat data and sender & receiver have to store the private and public keys to regenerate the encryption key. But now we are leaving your original question and getting off-topic.

Comment: Uh, not really off-topic... from what I understand about Diffie-Hellman is that the Server is the place for sharing the keys right? That's why I'm asking about Firebase... if this is a misconception, I will delete the question about Firebase

... And Yes, the Firebase is only to store the encrypted message

Comment: Key Exchange means: each client is generating it's own keypair (private & public key). The clients are sending their public key to the other party, both build a shared secret key and use this key as encryption key for their chat. The firebase just saves all encrypted chats. That means as well that each client has to store the public key from each chat partner (or the encryption key) to reveal old chats. The private key key should get stored in a secure way (e.g. keystore with password access) because everyone with physical access to the device is been able to read the chat in cleartext).

Comment: Alright, how to transfer the keys from each other without using Firebase?